# Mapping a SQL View with no Primary Key to JPA Entity

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys

In my Java App I want to get information that is stored in my Oracle Database, using JPA.
In my Database I have a View, with a set of columns that I got from some other tables. I want to map that View. However, my **View doesn't have a Primary Key**, so I can't create a JPA Entity. I thought about **use 2 columns as Foreign Keys**.

What's the best way of implementing that? I've seen so many different approaches, that I can't decide which is the best for this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to solve this is use a composite primary key by just adding the @Id annotation to the appropriate fields.

Comment: Thanks, using a Composite Primary Key (with @IdClass annotation) solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks this is the solution, adding the @Id to the view solved my problem, i am using Arquillian so i had to add the entity for the view and add another field to add the primary key

Answer (score 4):

There is no best approach. As that is a View, you will never insert any data in it, meaning you can simply define a Primary Key over any of existing fields. Also you could try to mark that field with `insertable=false, updatable=false`.

**UPDATE**

You know better your data, but *in general* in a view you cannot guarantee that all records are unique, which is why you should *in general* avoid working directly with entities from the view. I would suggest rather working with a Wrapper class, something like:

```
SELECT new com.domain.MyWrapper(field1, field2, field3, field4,...) FROM ViewEntity
```

Comment: That doesn't work when I get information about rows in the table in which the field set as Primary Key has equal content. No error is given, but the information comes changed.

Comment: If I had seen your answer some time ago, I'd never make a view on the Database and map it as an Entity. Uniqueness killed my app reports, and I almost gave up of my project because of that... Thank you